# MySQL query returning more results than it should

Tags: mysql

I have this query;

```
SELECT * FROM (`products`) WHERE `show_in_store` = 1 AND 
`category` = '8' AND `stock` >= 0 AND `name` LIKE '%a%' 
 OR `description` LIKE '%a%' ORDER BY `product_id` asc
```

It should return only a few results (those with category set to 8), but it returns everything, included results that have different categories...

Does the LIKE function over write the AND statement, or is it an ordering issue?

Comment: Some parentheses perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as

```
SELECT * FROM `products`
WHERE 
 `show_in_store` = 1 
  AND `category` = '8' 
  AND `stock` >= 0 
  AND ( `name` LIKE '%a%' OR `description` LIKE '%a%')
 ORDER BY `product_id` asc
```